# VirtualBox shared folder headless

Tags: apt, virtualbox, headless

I'd like to access a shared folder on my host Windows 7 computer with a minimal Ubuntu 16.04 server VM running on VirtualBox. Looking at the many posts about this it appears the first step is to install the Guest Additions package

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

I was rather shocked to find that this would add 271MB to my install after adding a large number of packages, including `virtualbox-guest-x11` and `x11-common` and multiple other x11-related packages. This seems the opposite of the intent of the package, which in `apt-cache show virtualbox-guest-utils` is described as `non-x11 guest utilities`.

Is there some other way to get support for shared folders without dragging in X11 packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`virtualbox-guest-utils` [recommends](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/virtualbox-guest-utils) `virtualbox-guest-x11`, and by default Apt installs recommended packages as dependencies. You can prevent this by using the `--no-install-recommends` flag:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends virtualbox-guest-utils
```